# jboss 7 domain:threads configuration

Tags: jboss7.x, threadpool

I was configuring an AJP connector on my JBoss7.1.1.Final. I assigned a thread pool to that connector whith some "bad" configuration:

```
<bounded-queue-thread-pool name="ajp-executor">
    <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
    <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
    <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
</bounded-queue-thread-pool>
```

I shutdown and startup my JBoss and standalone.xml came up with another configuration:

```
<bounded-queue-thread-pool name="ajp-executor">
    <core-threads count="90"/>
    <queue-length count="90"/>
    <max-threads count="90"/>
    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
</bounded-queue-thread-pool>
```

which is a correct one. Ok, JBoss removed the "bad" configurations. But, why count is 90? How JBoss computed this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the examples I've looked at have both a count and a per-cpu attribute set, as in your configuration, and I've been trying to figure out what exactly that means. Check out this page: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ThreadPoolConfiguration

> per-cpu - optional float attribute; specifies a quantity which is
>   multiplied by the number of available CPUs.  Both quantities are then
>   added and the final result is the actual count used. - See more at:
>   https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ThreadPoolConfiguration#sthash.OH93iLwC.dpuf

So I think what is happening is it is taking the "per-cpu" attribute of 20 and multiplying it by 4 (assuming you have four CPUs?) to get 80, and then adding your "count" to get a total of 90.

```
10 + (20 * 4) = 90
```